# Makefile target depend on file from environment variable

Tags: makefile, dependencies, environment-variables, target

if I run `make` like this:

```
make VAR=dir
```

is there a way to add the location pointed by the VAR variable as a target dependency? actually, I need to define a file inside that directory as a dependency.

I'd go with:

```
target: $(VAR)/file.txt
  echo yes
```

but if the variable was not defined, the target will understand `/file.txt`, which is not what I want. I also thought about creating a phony target to check for the variable, with `test`, but then the phony target would be executed every time and, consequently, `target` also would.

any solution to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't said what behavior you want if the variable is not defined, but this is probably what you want:

```
ifdef VAR
target: $(VAR)/file.txt
endif

target:
  echo yes
  @echo and here are the dependencies: $^
```

Comment: thanks, that was what I needed. actually, I'd use an `else` clause to enclose the last target so make won't complain about redefining a target.

Comment: Make won't complain, and the trick won't work if you put the second part in an `else` clause. Try it.